# What are the functions of the multimedia keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I got a [Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/L5V-00001), but sadly the product manual does not explain the multimedia keys.

[image: Picture of F5-F8]

[image: Picture of F9-F12]

Some of them are easy to figure out:

- <kbd>F1</kbd> - Play / Pause
- <kbd>F2</kbd> - Mute audio
- <kbd>F3</kbd> - Volume down
- <kbd>F4</kbd> - Volume up
- <kbd>F5</kbd> - Search
- <kbd>F6</kbd> - Share
- <kbd>F7</kbd> - Devices
- <kbd>F8</kbd> - Settings
- <kbd>F9</kbd> - ?
- <kbd>F10</kbd> - Flip3D
- <kbd>F11</kbd> - ?
- <kbd>F12</kbd> - ?

I am using Windows 7, so <kbd>F5</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> do not have any function (except for <kbd>F10</kbd> which invokes Flip3D).

So what do <kbd>F9</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> do on Windows 8?

PS: I have figured out how to program these keys, see my question - [What are the virtual key codes for the Windows 8 specific multimedia keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685284/what-are-the-virtual-key-codes-for-the-windows-8-specific-multimedia-keys/23685285#23685285) - from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you please add a close up picture of the keys? I am unable to see them from my device, they're too small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>F9</kbd> - Display Switch
- <kbd>F11</kbd> - Horizontal Display
- <kbd>F12</kbd> - Vertical Display Orientation

Depending on your driver and screen config these keys work... or not. I have the same keyboard and they don't work under win8.1.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere or did you find out by trial and error?

Comment: I went through the online documentation and couldn't find it!